# How to execute a daemon on the server from JQuery with Ajax (Linux server with PHP5)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make Ajax start a daemon on the server with the following JQuery code.  The alert pops up but the daemon doesn't start.  What is the proper way to format the section that is $.ajax({data: {},;  to make this code work.  I have been searching for hours for an example related directly to this but came up only with broad scoped and convoluted piles of generally stinky poopoo-lery:) Thanks.

UPDATE

I am still unable to launch the daemon.  I have added a php file on the server as recommended which is called "executedp.php". It contains a script I hoped would accomplish the task. However, it has not.

Does anyone see what I am missing.

Here is the php code for executedp.php:

```
<?php $startDaemon = exec('sh ~/.devilspie/ruleset.sh $x; done'); ?>
```

Here is the updated JQuery code:

```
        if(found) {
        var xhr = $.ajax({ 
        url: 'executedg.php',
        success: alert("It has begun!")  
        }); 

        switch($.tableCount) {

        case ($.tableCount = 1):
        window.open('table1.html');
        xhr;
        break;          

        case ($.tableCount = 2):
        window.open('table1.html');
        window.open('table2.html');
        xhr;
        break;

        case ($.tableCount = 3):
        window.open('table1.html');
        window.open('table2.html');
        window.open('table3.html');
        xhr;
        break;

        case ($.tableCount = 4):
        window.open('table1.html');
        window.open('table2.html');
        window.open('table3.html');
        window.open('table4.html');
        xhr;
        break;
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you invoke the XmlHttpRequest (xhr), you must indicate an URL / URI to be executed on the remote server. In the script contained in this URI is where you have to start your daemon.

You need something more apart from just client side coding (Jquery), but also some server side scripting.

**EDITED**: I think you are messing the old school XmlHttpRequest and $.ajax.
The code you have only makes the ajax request on the first invocation, when you define *xhr*.
When you reference the *xhr* object again, inside the *switch* command, the ajax call is not being fired.

Comment: Ok, I created executedg.php on the server which contains: `code`$startDaemon = `/home/dealer/gdevilspie-0.31/gdevilspie; $x; done`;`code`and added url: 'executedg.php' to the ajax code but still not clear on how to call it from the ajax script.

Comment: I think it is enough with: $.ajax({url: 'executedg.php'}); More information here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Sorry about the code tags in the reply, not sure how to do it.  @jap1968

Comment: Same problem here!

Comment: Still no luck. I have updated the code with what I have done so far. @jap1968